# Attribute in drop down meniu in product page

Tags: dropdown-attribute

Can you clue me how to add this attribute into order process? Let's say that i have a bike and some customer prefers a specific frame size, but that bike came in different frame sizes. How can i add a drop-down where he can select frame size and complete the order. The frame size will not affect the price...

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [configurable products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product).
You should need to create a configurable products with the configurable attribute `frame_size` and one simple product for each frame size option.
Then the customer can choose the framesize from the product view page and add it to the cart.